# LCD TV through HDMI without duplicating display

Tags: display, hdmi, tv

I have an LCD TV that is connected to the PC with a HDMI cable. I usually select "Duplicate these displays" in display options. This also means that both the monitor and TV will do the same thing.

Is there anyway of accomplishing this without duplicating the displays? On the TV to watch a movie for instance and my monitor to remain free?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your graphics driver, there should be a tool that will allow you to configure how to handle multiple displays. Usually windows has a check-box in the display control panel for 'Extend my desktop onto this display' that you will want to select.

Comment: "Extend my desktop" will take my directly to the TV display (a screen with my wallpaper and nothing else). I will try to find out more about the option or program. I have a 5770 ATI HD graphics card.

Comment: Yes. You're correct. You should be able to drag windows onto it, however, which will allow you to watch movies, etc.  Specifically, you may need to make this your primary display so that you can put graphics-accelerated applications (like the video) on it.  That is, however, exactly the way you describe what you want to do.